# How to create wxpython app that attach to top and shift desktop size, like Taskbar?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am using WxPython (phoenix), and at the moment trying to create Taskbar replacement in Windows 10, always on top, and at the top edge of the screen. Surely, it will make my app cover window beneath it.

How do I make the desktop shrink to allow my app attach itself to the top edge of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Woops, sorry, doing a quick google, I found this: https://github.com/sabren/ceomatic/blob/master/wxappbars.py

Only need to change for has_key error and GetMetrics to wx.SystemSettings.GetMetric per Phoenix changes